# How to catch files with same names but different extensions in Linux and delete them

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-16.04

OS - Ubuntu 16.04

My goal is simple. There are multiple images in a folder say

```
A.jpg
A.jpeg
B.jpg
B.jpeg
C.jpg
```

I want the names of the jpg files who have a .jpeg copy. So in this case I want the names A.jpg and B.jpg. Note that I do not want C.jpg because it does not have a jpeg copy.

Next, I want to delete the .jpg files whose names I have. So in this case I want to delete A.jpg and B.jpg ONLY.

Is there a set of commands to do it ?
(I indented the file names because for some reason stackoverflow was telling me it is code.)

**EDIT**

Is there someway I could put those filenames in a txt file and then read from it to delete the required files?

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do echo ${file%.*}.jpg; done
```

If this is what you want, just replace 'echo' by 'rm'

(Edited) This way you won't see errors for non-existing files:

```
for file in *.jpeg; do [[ -f ${file%.*}.jpg ]] && rm ${file%.*}.jpg; done
```

Comment: The command successfully tells me the names of the files that have a jpeg copy but when I replace `echo` with `rm` it fails to delete them. It reports an error for each file saying rm: cannot remove 'imagename' : No such file or directory

Comment: Can you show me the output?
Anyway for those jpeg files that does not have jpg it will fail, just ignore these errors.

Answer (score 1):

This may be:

```
#!/bin/sh

JPG_LIST="*.jpg"
#JPG_LIST=$(cat JPG_filenames_to_test.txt)

for filename in $JPG_LIST; do
    BASENAME="${filename%.*}"
    echo -n "Basename '$BASENAME': "
    if [ -e $BASENAME.jpg -a -e $BASENAME.jpeg ] ; then
        echo "$BASENAME.jpeg found. Removing $BASENAME.jpg"
        rm $BASENAME.jpg
    else
        echo "No $BASENAME.jpeg file found. Keeping original $BASENAME.jpg"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I copy-pasted this in the terminal opened in the folder and it did nothing, didn't even print a name

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar Hm... I've tested this in my terminal and it works. For the script to print anything, you need to have both SAMENAME.jpg  **and**  SAMENAME.jpeg.

Comment: I have that `SAMENAME.jpg` and `SAMENAME.jpeg`. What I did was copy paste this in gedit and save it as delete.sh in the image folder and then run the command bash delete.sh but it outputs nothing and did nothing.

Comment: This script assumes the files are literally named `A.jpg`, `B.jpg`, etc, which is highly unlikely to be the case. (Aside from that, it's deleting the wrong file of each pair.)

Comment: @cHao sir can you please help me out with this. I am supposed to work with 1500+ images and this is a part of it

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar: Pablo's answer is about what i'd have written. It should get you quite a ways.

Comment: @cHao True. So I fixed it a bit.

Comment: @TanmayBhatnagar Hm... Still works on my PC. See session recording for reference https://asciinema.org/a/IjE5utO94xMaJ6Y3f7vRgRRAe . Hope it helps.